# how to copy Amazon issued Cert from one region to another

Tags: amazon-web-services

I am trying to copy amazon issued cert from one region to another, I don't see any private, intermediate and public key with amazon issued one, how to copy it?

Answer (score 1):

You can't. You have to request a new cert in the other region.